# Java ChargeAccount program array

Tags: java, class

I am new to java. Working in the book titled starting out with java from control structure through objects.

My assignment is as followed: create a class method that accepts a charge account number as its argument. The method should determine whether the number is valid by comparing it to the following list of valid charge account numbers:

5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 8080152,
    4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 1250255, 1005231, 6545231,
    3852085, 7576651, 7881200, 4581002\

These numbers should be stored in an array or an ArrayList object. Use a sequential search to locate the number passed as an argument. if the number is in the array, the method should return true, indicating the number is valid. if the number is not in the array, the method should return false, indicating the number is invalid.

My question goes along, is the program I have enough, or do I have to create a separate class?

the problem i'm having is this chapter seems different from the previous. we just got done with chapter 6 which was classes and that required me to make a main project and a constructor. my question is, are arrays just one program? or am i missing something. the program seems to run okay. if you could clear  this up for me that would be awesome.

My question is: in chapter 6, I had to create two programs. One the main and second the class for example. One was the constructor, the other was the main in which it spoke to the constructor.

Do arrays require two programs or is the program I wrote sufficient enough?

the program code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ChargeAccount {
    static int[] validChargeAccountNumbers = {
        5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 8080152,
        4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 1250255, 1005231, 6545231,
        3852085, 7576651, 7881200, 4581002
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // ask the user for an account number
        System.out.print("Enter the account number: ");

        // get the number from the user
        int number = in.nextInt();

        // check to see if the number is valid
        if (ChargeAccount.isValid(number) == true) 
        {
                System.out.println("Fraud account detected.");
        } else 
        {
                System.out.println("That number is invalid.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < validChargeAccountNumbers.length; i++) {
            //checks if the numbers were in the list
            if (validChargeAccountNumbers[i] == number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I apologize if any formatting is wrong. please ask me any questions.

Comment: What is the question exactly? If it is "are arrays just one program?" please explain what that means in more detail.

Comment: @Thilo I updated the question. if it is not more clear I do apologize.

Comment: I think they just want you to put the `main` method into its own class.

Comment: Two files containing a class with the main method and another class used within the main method represent a single program. You could compare that with a machine made-up of different parts.

Comment: It's not uncommon to have an `AccountApp`, for example, which would have the `main` and thus the entry point for your program. You then can write any number of *useful* classes which will help you in your task. This isn't necessary, but good practice, IMHO. This also allows you to, if not experienced in other ways, to use the `main` in the other classes as a tester by compiling and running that class alone.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have updated it with more information

Comment: It looks fine to me; does it work? I'd say there's nothing in the description that *demands* an additional class, so it's up to you. I would say you should give the material another look. Asking if arrays require two programs makes me think 2 things, you're not understanding data structures, and you may want to convince yourself that there's a difference between classes and programs.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils  you are right. I am not fully understanding data structures and probably will benefit from going over it some more. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like this has to do with learning Object Oriented Programming.

In this case, you would have one file, ChargeAccount.java, which would contain that code, and maybe ChargeAccountTest.java, which would contain the rest of the code.

In OOP, constructors instantiate objects, like you did with the Scanner object, calling new Scanner() called the Scanner constructor. Research how to create constructors and how to call them in other classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{   
    ChargeAccount account = new ChargeAccount();
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is object oriented programming. I apologize if that was not made clear.

Answer (score 2):

As he said it is nothing to with learning Object Oriented Programming.

It is all about our how effectively we designed the code.

The above answer is perfectly fine, place the business logic code in one class ChargerAccount.java

And Create the rest of the code in another class to test the logic.

Comment: Just a hint: You may want to avoid saying things like "the above answer" because their positions, as you can now see, aren't static :)